# Sublime Text: text list of open files

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have some files opened in sublime text. I can see that list on the side panel. I want to know if there is a plugin that can give me this list as text. i.e., I hit a button and new file pops up that has lists all the open file names.

```
4 open files: 

open_file_1.cc
open_file_1.h
open_file_2.cc
open_file_2.h
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wrote a small plugin for this as I could not find anything. Pasting it here so that someone can use it if needed in future.

```
https://github.com/rrg/ListOpenFiles
```

Comment: Searching for "ListOpenFiles" in Package Control (as you suggested in that github link) didn't work for me-- is the plugin ST2 compatible only?

Comment: Got it to work again, https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ListOpenFiles if you care about why it was missing from package repository for a while here is the thread https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/pull/3357

Comment: Can you please look into my current question, maybe you add a feature to your plugin to write list of files into a file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344126/list-files-that-are-currently-opened-in-sublime-3

Answer (score 10):

Press:

```
Ctrl ` (Control-backtick)
```

To open up Sublime's internal Python console. Then run the following command:

```
print("\n".join([view.file_name() for view in sublime.active_window().views() if view and view.file_name()]));
```

The console should print a newline-separated list of the full paths to your open files. Note that this is a bit of a hack since Sublime's console doesn't support multiline Python. The main advantage here is that you don't have to install anything.

Comment: Any idea how to retrieve the last cursor location in each of those files?

Comment: To get the open files of _all_ Sublime windows: `print("\n".join([view.file_name() for window in sublime.windows() for view in window.views() if view and view.file_name()]))`

Answer (score 3):

This plugin should be fairly easy to modify to suit your needs:

https://github.com/phildopus/sublime-goto-open-file

Comment: yes I looked at that plugin, it is pretty similar. I will take a look at writing sublime plugins and python if no one has any other solution. Thanks.